# Lipschitz continuity of derivative of $l_p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

Let
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\|x\|_{l^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}^2=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^p\Big)^\frac{2}{p},
$$
for $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is the gradient of $F(x)$, i.e. $G(x)=\nabla F(x)$ Lipschitz continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Indeed the function $G$ will look like below:
$$
G(x)=(\sum_{j=1}^{m}|x_j|^{p}\Big)^\frac{2-p}{p}(|x_1|^{p-2}x_1,\ldots,|x_n|^{p-2}x_n).
$$
I can only see that for $p=2$, since $G(x)=x$ for $p=2$ and hence Lipschitz continuous. What about $p>2$? Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: My first impression is:  yes "G" is Lipschitz for all $p>2$ too. Notice that we can show that $c_{1} \sum_{j=1}^{m}|x_j|\leq (\sum_{j=1}^{m}|x_j|^{p})^{1/p}\leq c_{2} \sum_{j=1}^{m}|x_j|$ for some $c_{1},c_{2}>0$ that depend only on $n,p$.

Comment: Another possible idea is to bound the "derivative" of $G$. So, this is definitely has to do with the Hessian matrix.

Comment: I don't think for other values of $p$ will $G$ be Lipschitz continuous. The reason is that if $p > 2,$ then you can consider $x \approx 0$ while for $p < 2,$ you consider $\|x\| \approx \infty.$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate with your answer. I also tried MVT, but could not proceed much.

Comment: Let us look for the mean-value theorem for vector fields :)

Comment: Yes, but that includes the gradient which might blow up near the origin when $p>2$.

Comment: @Mathguide Do you agree with my first comment ? if so, then you see that $|G(x)|\sim 1$ for both small and large $x$.